# Horizontal alignment of subfigures in PGFplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, memoir, subfloats

I have 4 subfigures in a 2x2 grid. The figures are made in Matlab by using matlab2tikz, and hence the TikZ files are inputted. The problem is, that the y-ticks are different and therefore the subfigures (see (a) and (c)) have different widths. As you can see from the figure below, I would like to vertically align the right-hand side of subfigures (a) and (c) without manually adding a `\hspace` before subfigure (a). How is this done?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \newlength\figureheight 
    \newlength\figurewidth 
    \setlength\figureheight{0.4\textwidth}
    \setlength\figurewidth{0.35\textwidth}
    \subbottom[Subcaption1]{\input{flowUniformityOutletSimple_n.tikz}}
    \hfill
    \subbottom[Subcaption2]{\input{flowUniformityOutletFail_n.tikz}}
    %
    \subbottom[Subcaption3]{\input{flowUniformityOutletSimple_t.tikz}}
    \hfill
    \subbottom[Subcaption4]{\input{flowUniformityOutletFail_t.tikz}}
    \caption{Main caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: subfigures]

Comment: You could possibly set the width of the ticklabels to the same in all cases with something like `'extraAxisOptions','yticklabel style={text width={width("$-0.6$")},align=right}'` for `matlab2tikz`, where `$-0.6$` is the widest ticklabel.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. This seems to work well. Would you mind making it an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this is a little bit tricky, as there so many things influencing the size, but for this case, where the ticklabels on the y-axis are the only thing causing problems, you could try adding

```
'extraAxisOptions','yticklabel style={text width= width("$-0.6$")},align=right}'
```

the `matlab2tikz` calls, where `$-0.6$` is the widest ticklabel.

---

As a sidenote, I suggest moving

```
\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth 
\setlength\figureheight{0.4\textwidth}
\setlength\figurewidth{0.35\textwidth}
```

to the preamble (before `\begin{document}`), and only redefine the lengths in those `figure` environments where you need to.

---

For aligning multiple axes with `pgfplots` like this I would usually recommend using a single `tikzpucture` and the features of the `groupplots` library (see `pgfplots` manual), but that will lead to a quite a bit more work, and a lot of modifications to the LaTeX code.

Just for reference, in case anyone is interested, here is one way of using `groupplots` in this context, also integrating numbered subcaptions. One obvious drawback is the need for some manual adjustment of the spacing between axes, but that fairly easily done by modifying the `vertical sep` (and `horizontal sep`) in the `group style`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,units}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.9,
  unit code/.code 2 args={\si{#1#2}} % from manual, for using siunitx to typeset units
}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth 
\setlength\figureheight{0.4\textwidth}
\setlength\figurewidth{0.35\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  width=\figurewidth,
  height=\figureheight,
  scale only axis,
  title style={
    at={(xticklabel cs:0.5)},
    below=4ex,
    text width=\figurewidth},
  group style={
    group size=2 by 2,
    vertical sep=2cm,
    horizontal sep=1.5cm},
  ylabel=$v_n$,xlabel=$y$,
  y unit=\m\per\s,x unit=\cm,
  domain=4:5,samples=10,
]
\nextgroupplot[title={\subcaption{Subcaption 1}}]
  \addplot {x};

\nextgroupplot[title={\subcaption{Subcaption 2}}]
  \addplot {x^2};

\nextgroupplot[title={\subcaption{Subcaption 3. A longer one that will break across lines.}}]
  \addplot {-x};

\nextgroupplot[title={\subcaption{Subcaption 4}}]
  \addplot {x^2 + 4};

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Main caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]